# The "new" Top Bar is now active on Web Apps

Tags: discussion, top-bar

[image: new top bar]

From [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/21960)

> I’m excited to announce that the top bar design that has been on Stack Overflow for several months is coming soon to the Stack Exchange network.
>
> ...
>
> To meet the needs of the network we needed to adjust some aspects of the design to work with the full range of sites. The design is coherent with the SO design, but isn’t exactly the same. The biggest difference is that site name and Questions/Tags/Users navigation remain below the top bar. This was needed in order to work with sites with long names and/or custom skins.
>
> Most importantly, the site switcher and other key controls will be in the same location across the entire network
>
> ...
>
> If this change is new to you, then check out the [How Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/) blog post and the meta post [Has the top bar redesign met its goals?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals/349386#349386) for more details.

See also: [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/21960)

Comment: thanks for posting the update!